# I need to speed up the code that contains mod operation

Tags: memory, optimization, modulo

I have the following math equation

```
for(i=0;i<M;i++)
for(j=0;j<M;j++)
R=((A(i)+B(j))%M)*M+(C(i)+D(j))%M;
```

In C code, I have tried to speed up the code and I find that if I remove the mod operation it becomes 6 times faster, but I can't remove it
But in the values of A,B,C and D are between 0 and M, so I have four cases

First if A+B and C+D less than M no need for a mod operation

```
R=R
```

Second if A+B less than M and C+D more than M I just need to make

```
R=R-M
```

Third if A+B and C+D more than M then I need \

```
R=R-M*M-M
```

Last if A+B more than M and C+D less than M then I need

```
R=R-M*M
```

If I implement it using if else it time consuming ? So any suggestion

Comment: What does "A(i)" mean? You are using C/C++ syntax, which would mean A is a function... did you mean "A * i"?

Comment: A,B,C and D are dynamic arrays of type uint_fast16_t, I am using C on codeblock, Those arrays contain uint_fast16_t values

Comment: M may be any value not necessary to be multiple of 2

Comment: If M is a power of 2 then %M can be computed easily with a mask... I'm assuming it isn't a power of 2 - what do you know about M?  How large can it be?  You say A,B,C and D are between 0 and M, and are representable in 16 bits, does that mean M is also 16-bits?

Comment: M depend on the image size M=sqrt(L*C*P*8), so it must be of the same type of the A,B,C and D, Yes it is uint_fast16_t

Comment: Okay, you are doing image processing.  Is the addition (A(i)+B(j)) a saturating add? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic